# Format a list from Nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, html, twitter-bootstrap

In the [Demo](http://helloworld.site44.com) 
When you click a place and more information it shows the list like:

```
    Session ID 1
    Session ID 2

    User abc
    User xyz
```

I am not able to make it like

```
    Session ID 1 <---- Click.. then shows below list of users
         User xyz    //List of users under Session ID 1

    Session ID 2 <---- Click.. then shows below list of users
         User abc    //List of users under Session ID 2
```

The [JSON](http://helloworld.site44.com/sample.json)

Comment: You should post the code you've tried so far.

Comment: And how it's related to twitter-bootstrap ?

Comment: According to your markup, there are 2 separate lists for each modal window. You add the session id to the first and the names to the other. You should change the way you parse your list if you wish to get the desired result. In addition, your approach won't scale. I would suggest caching the JSON object and using the same modal window or show the list directly within the info window, parsing the stored data to obtain the currently required data.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var list = '<li>' + data.sessions[i].ID + '<ul>';
$.each(locations.a, function(i, value) {
   list += '<li>' + '<i class="icon-user"></i>' + value.id +  value.name + '</li>');
});
list += "</ul></li>";
$(".ID1").append(list);
```

I believe this would work. If the second ul doesn't appear like you want just style it appropriately.

In the end you need this structure

```
<li>
   ID
   <ul>
     <li></li>
     <li></li>
     ...
   <ul>
</li>
```

Comment: No not you. Someone else downvoted. meh, anyway.

Comment: upvoted you to make it fair :P

Comment: And I did the same now :) thanks